# How to restore the screen sharing control panel in Zoom?

Tags: uninstall, screen, deb, zoom-meeting

I used a second screen demo. When I clicked on the arrow button on the green box (it can be seen in the attached image) at this point the screen sharing control panel disappeared. I don't know how to restore it.

Now it turns out that I can start screen sharing, but I cannot end it. I can't control screen sharing at all. No hotkeys help. Reinstalling the program does not help. Can anyone please help?

At least help me reset all settings so that the program is like new.

ps. Sorry for my English

screen sharing control panel

[image: img_screen_sharing]

Comment: I don't know how to restore it, but I find that if I click and drag the window (to any position) before it disappears, then it doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue but managed to resolve it with un-/installing the application. I use the [zoom-client](https://snapcraft.io/zoom-client) Snap, though. First, I uninstalled the Snap in the Software Center. Then, I completely removed the `~/snap/zoom-client` directory. Finally, I installed the Snap again. This reset the configuration, including the visibility of the screen sharing controls.

I also had a look at the configuration files in `~/snap/zoom-client` but I couldn't find any that seemed relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The zoom client is buggy, I found a solution for this, but note the following may cause you to lose your configured settings of zoom, or maybe your chat history, however, these are not important to me so I just did it, and no losses:

1. remove the `~/.zoom/` folder
2. open zoom and relogin with your account
3. enter a new meeting and share screen, the control panel appears again!